# Check values from the list and assign to string in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

I have a `List` in which currently there are 13 (STATE with a Name) values.

```
List<UMSLocationDetails> UMSLocationDetails = (List<UMSLocationDetails>)Session["lstUMSLocationDetails"];
```

So I want to check if in this list `Rajashtan` is there or not. If exists I want to assign it to a `string` variable.

I can get it if I pass a hardcode value like below:

```
UMSLocationDetails[6].LocationName
```

Which gives me `Rajashtan`. But I want it dynamically.

Comment: `var item = UMSLocationDetails.Where(x => x.LocationName == "Rajashtan").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @VDWWD: here rajashtan you are passing is hardcode or not ?

Comment: Yes it is, why? At 2.7k rep I hope you can figure out you can replace a string with a variable yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault), as follows:

```
var location = UMSLocationDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocationName == "Rajashtan");
if (location != null)
{
    // do something with location / location.LocationName
}
```

Comment: If you are going off strings, might be worth trimming any whitespace and doing a to lower too, if the input is free text

Comment: There is no indication in the original question that that would be the case.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is better if you need to use the item if found, however if you need to know if it just exists try

```
var locationExists = UMSLocationDetails.Any(x => x.LocationName.ToLowerInvariant() == "rajashtan");
```

With new C# and it's null coalescing makes life a lot easier, referencing existing answer:

```
var locationName = UMSLocationDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocationName?.ToLowerInvariant().Trim() == "rajashtan")?.LocationName;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
string locationName = UMSLocationDetails.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LocationName == "Rajashtan")?.LocationName;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access by index [FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__)

```
    string state = "Rajashtan";
    int index = UMSLocationDetails.FindIndex(c => c.LocationName == state);
    if (index >= 0) 
    string locationName = UMSLocationDetails[index].LocationName;
```

If You want to find only exists and do anything else

```
    string state = "Rajashtan";
    bool exists = UMSLocationDetails.Any(c => c.LocationName == state);
    if (exists){}
```